# Set id for bootbox textarea

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, bootbox

Below is code to open `bootbox` with `textarea`:

```
bootbox.prompt({
  title: "This is title",
  inputType: 'textarea',
  placeholder: 'Feedback',
  callback: function (result) { console.log(result); }
});
```

I can see `textarea` created like below:

```
<textarea class="bootbox-input bootbox-input-textarea form-control" placeholder="Feedback"></textarea>
```

I tried to give id like: `id: "test_id",` but it is giving me an error. Can anyone help please?

*I am opening this bootbox on click of one button.*

Comment: what is the reason for downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add id by jQuery in simple way .

```
    bootbox.confirm({
      message: 'message',
      buttons: {
       'confirm': {
         title: "This is title",
         inputType: 'textarea',
         placeholder: 'Feedback',
         label: 'OK',
         className:'bootbox-input bootbox-input-textarea form-control'
        }
     },
     callback: function(result) {
       if (result) {
        console.log("OK clicked");
       }
      }
    });

    $(".bootbox-input-textarea").attr('id', 'bootbox-confirm-id');

<textarea class="bootbox-input bootbox-input-textarea form-control" placeholder="Feedback"></textarea>
```

For more information , visit the **[LINK](https://github.com/makeusabrew/bootbox/issues/598)**

Comment: comments are gone!

Comment: can you pls post again to remove focus from the textarea?

Comment: I have deleted that file from my PC . i will get back to you after some time . I am in middle of some work . @PathikVejani

Comment: Ok! No issue..!

Comment: hey! any luck??

Comment: Not yet bro .. Badly struct in restructuring project .. Sorry for it

Comment: No issues, I figured out it. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for it ... Thank you so much

Comment: No issues, can understand!

Answer (score -1):

```
function openBootbox () {
  bootbox.prompt({
    title: "This is title",
    inputType: 'textarea',
    placeholder: 'Feedback',
    callback: function (result) { console.log(result); }
  });
}
```

Hit this **openBootbox** function on any button click

Comment: bt how to set id for `textarea`?

Comment: May be it does not work , how you want it to work getting element by id.
http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html